# Casting exception during form validation of nested:select (Struts 1.3.10)

Tags: struts, nested

I am now trying to dig into struts framework and now, I am testing nested-tags. I encounter problem when I retrieve data. My code is as following :

```
            <nested:select property="formatDisponible">
                <logic:iterate id="listFormat" property="formatList" name="videoGameForm">
                <html:option value="${listFormat}" />
                </logic:iterate>
            </nested:select>
```

When I perform validation action (by that I mean retrieving data from my form) I got the following exception:

`GRAVE: Method invocation failed.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@110e3b5
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)`

Thank you for your help (I will update you about any change).

I finally found what was going wrong in my previous code. If somehow, other people are facing the same problem, I am going to put the correct code below.

```
            <nested:nest property="formatDisponible">
                <nested:select property="id">
                    <html:options collection="formatList" property="id" labelProperty="nom" labelName="id"></html:options>
                </nested:select>
            </nested:nest>
```

I corrected my first test and ended up with that solution. The only thing I am trying to figure out right now is how to set selected value (because I am using this form to update my object). If I can resolve it, I will update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my problem related to this question was solved (at least for now). I accidentally overloaded the value of the select property.